# Flutter - PageView swipe doesn't work with TextField as a child

Tags: flutter

I have a `PageView` widget which has as children some pages where there is `TextField` in it. When I try to swipe to change page, the swipe only works if I swipe outsize the `TextField` area, as if the widget is stealing the gesture.

How can I prevent that? I already tried to wrap the children in a `IgnorePointer`, but this basically disables the `TextField`, I can not even tap it to write.

EDIT: the problem seems to be only on iOS, on Android works

Comment: What does your widget tree look like? I tried to create a similar case and it's working fine, you can check the code [here](https://gist.github.com/dhafinrayhan/a63f94e0bb09ed7a2334c09c79012f14)

Comment: @DhafinRayhan actually works, but only on android. Does it work on iPhone on your side?

Answer (score 0):

The behavior you're observing on iOS with the TextField widget intercepting gestures meant for the PageView is a common issue due to the way gesture recognition works differently across platforms. iOS tends to be a bit more... let's say "possessive," about its gestures. Try this:

```
PageController _controller = PageController();

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return GestureDetector(
    onHorizontalDragStart: (DragStartDetails details) {
      // Your logic to determine if the swipe should start
    },
    onHorizontalDragUpdate: (DragUpdateDetails details) {
      // Your logic to handle swipe updates
    },
    onHorizontalDragEnd: (DragEndDetails details) {
      // Your logic to handle swipe end
    },
    child: PageView(
      controller: _controller,
      children: <Widget>[
        // Your pages with TextFields
      ],
      onPageChanged: (int page) {
        // Your logic to handle page changes
      },
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: not working on iphone

Comment: edited try this approach

Answer (score 0):

Please review the code below, which I hope will be helpful to you.

```
GestureDetector(
      behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
      onPanDown: (_) {
        FocusScope.of(context)
            .unfocus(); // Dismiss the keyboard when user taps on the TextField
      },
      child: AbsorbPointer(
        absorbing: false, // Initially absorb gestures
        child: Center(
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
            child: TextField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                hintText: 'Enter text...',
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```